# How to rename user folder in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-account

When I log in on a Windows 8 machine for the first time with my Microsoft Account (by providing an e-mail address), a new user folder is created:

```
C:\Users\dzinx_000
```

In previous versions of Windows, I could choose the name of this folder (it was equal to my username). As I use the commandline often, it is quite annoying to me.

- Can I somehow rename it to `dzinx`?
- Does simply renaming the folder break everything?

Comment: I would assume that simply trying rename the folder would break things.

Comment: As a workaround, you can use the `%userprofile%` environment variable as a shortcut to your user folder. So `cd %userprofile%` is equivalent to `cd C:\Users\dzinx_000`.

Comment: @ChrisF yeah, that's what I'm suspecting, that's why I'm asking :)

Comment: Can you log in as another user and rename the original user?

Comment: @ChrisF I don't know, I'm afraid to try :)

Comment: I just found out that while it's difficult to change an already existing username, it's easier to choose one when logging in with a Microsoft Account for the first time -- see [my answer](http://superuser.com/a/495848/3774)

Comment: Also check out this [link](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2012/09/how-to-change-user-profile-location-in-windows-8-without-registry-hack/) & [MSKB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314843#XSLTH3129121125120121120120).

Comment: I found something when digging the settings the other day. I'll see again and let you know. I actually changed my username. Windows put it to Pratyush. I made it to Pratyush Nalam. Although in my case, no annoying _000 was there

Comment: @ChrisF: Yes it does, you'll be logged into a temporary profile afterwards.

Answer (score 185):

There are two different approaches, depending on if you have ever used the Microsoft account on the given computer:

## I have already logged into that account

1. Create a local user account with administrative privileges if you don't have one already.
2. Reboot.
3. Login with local account with administrative privileges.
4. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd> (**Computer Management**) → **System Tools** → **Local Users and Groups** → **Users**, right-click user, **Rename**.
5. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd> (**Command Prompt (Admin)**)

   ```
   ren C:\Users\dzinx_000 dzinx
   ```
6. <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> (**Run**)

   ```
   regedit
   ```
7. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\` and find the SID for your user account. You can simply open each folder and check the `ProfileImagePath` for the correct one.

   Rename the `ProfileImagePath` value to your desired name, like `C:\Users\dzinx`
8. Log in with your Microsoft account. Everything should work fine:

   [image]

## I have never logged into my Microsoft account

To start of, we only have one, local user account:

[image]

I'm now going to add my Microsoft account.

[image]

Now we have our Microsoft account. Let's open the **Computer Management** from the lower left corner.

[image]

Here we can see our new garbled user account:

[image]

Rename it!

[image]

You may note that no folder in `C:\Users` exists at this point in time.

[image]

Now log in with the new user account.

[image]

Now my Microsoft account is named "superuser" locally and the profile is stored in `C:\Users\superuser`

[image]

### I don't have the Professional edition :(

In the standard edition of Windows 8, the **Local Users and Groups** snap-in is not available.

In my tests, the following procedure worked out well. Your mileage may vary!

The procedure is identical to what was outlined under **I have already logged into that account**, except that I didn't use the **Local Users and Groups** snap-in. Instead, I went right for the command prompt and renamed the profile folder. Afterwards, I adjusted the `ProfileImagePath` key in the registry.

Additionally, I searched the whole registry for the full path of my userprofile (`C:\Users\Username`) and replaced all entries with the new folder name.

I couldn't detect any problems after rebooting and logging in with the renamed account, but, as I said, your mileage may vary.

### What happens when I simply rename `C:\Users\abc` to `C:\Users\xyz`?

After logging in with the affected user, the user will be logged into a temporary profile:
[image]
[image]

Comment: The most comprehensive answer! And it's easier to create user associated with Microsoft account, rename it before first sign in.

Comment: Is it not easier to create a new user account with the correct name, log into that one, migrate the old user profile to the new one, then delete the old account? Or is it not in W8?

Comment: @Moab It's a bit different with Microsoft accounts. Unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg you are right, they are asking about a Microsoft account.

Comment: looks like this WILL NOT WORK on windows 8 standard edition...being that there is not users and groups

Comment: If you have picture password enabled with a pic in your profile folder which you want to rename, you will not able to do the 5th step, because the picture is using the folder. Just reboot again so the default login is not the one you want to rename...

Comment: I've changed the registry entry as described above because I had already started using the account. There is however a problem whenever I install new applications it still remembers that old username from somewhere and is the default location sometimes when saving User folders... Where else is it getting this information?

Comment: @user64908: You might want to check with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and possibly open another question.

Comment: I got "access denied" after step 5 (I use Microsoft account to log in). Is there any workaround?

Comment: @KiL: Are you performing the operation from an elevated command prompt?

Comment: Yes. I logged into a local admin account and use admin cmd to type  rename command but it prompt "access denied". My user folder has a non-english character so I want to rename it.

Comment: @KiL: You could retry it in safe mode. If that doesn't work either, you may want to open a new question.

Comment: The steps under "I don't have the Professional edition :(" didn't work for me.  No matter how many times or ways I tried, I couldn't get all of the registry edits to stick after rebooting - they keep resetting to the original name.  So I can definitely confirm YMMV.

Comment: Also, you may want to update the values in...

HKEY_USERS\{{user_guid}}\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders

Comment: And in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders` too. I had a couple of problems with my software because it was unable to find user-related directories until I changed values there.

Comment: Good for newly created account. Though for new account it is easy to ditch it and create local account then link to MS one. There are many applications that keep an absolute path in the registry. If you do want to follow this answer, you'd have also to search & change all registry entries with your former folder path. Search first to assess the amount of work! For example, Dropbox will be a pain. Few Lenovo apps still write to old location for me. So it still needs to be paired with symlinking.

Comment: Hi, I followed your instruction and I got stucked with the *temporary profile* thing and somehow I lost all my files. Do you know if windows keep those stored somewhere? Thanks

Comment: Same problem as @KIL, "access denied" in step 5. Any update on how to solve that issue?

Comment: I used `netplwiz` to change my username in addition to the above steps.

Comment: Works under Windows 10 Professional. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: "I have already logged into that account" instructions work under windows 10 pro

Answer (score 16):

You could create a symbolic link to the folder. Symbolic links will transparently redirect.

Use `mklink` (as administrator) to create a symbolic link:

```
mklink /d C:\Users\dzinx C:\Users\dzinx_000
```

Comment: That IS kind of a solution, but the old username will still pop out in many places. Maybe there's a possibility to completely change the username?

Comment: @DzinX In previous versions of Windows, you could edit the subkeys of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` in the registry. One subkey will be for your user SID, and then you just change its `ProfileImagePath` value and rename the folder. However, this setting is just for Windows (and untested on Win8, but assumed to work). It is the path used to set `%userprofile%` on login, but badly coded programs may save the absolute path to your user profile and will break. I'm also uncertain how Modern UI apps will react, though I guess it depends, once again.

Comment: Huh, so if I both created the symlink AND changed registry settings, nothing should break but I shouldn't see `dzinx_000` too often, right?

Comment: @DzinX I guess it would be safest to change the main folder to `dzinx` through the registry (and rename) and then create a symlink from `dzinx_000` to `dzinx`. That way, only programs that specifically request the symlinked folder will use it. Of course, you could also try not having the symlink and see if anything does crash, then add it later.

Comment: If you have renamed a profile and fixed up the registry, making a link is a good practice to make sure that any references to c:\users\oldname will still work.  In theory you can crawl the registry and any config files to find them, but it is possible that you missed something.

Comment: There are _some_ obscure programs that will choke on symbolic links, but it is *rare*

Answer (score 7):

This guide is for **Windows XP/Vista** so try it at your own risk. I can't test it because I don't have a MS account.

Before we begin create a restore point or backup of your system drive. Backup your full registry in any case of data corruption.

> Though you can move or rename the user profile folder, there may be some side effects after using this method. This is because of the reason that there may be some absolute path references (to the old user profile folder) in the registry added by third-party software. Therefore, there may be a loss of functionality in the respective applications.

I got this information from [Change the Registered User and Company Name in Windows XP / Vista](http://www.petri.co.il/change_registered_user_and_company_vista_xp.htm).

If you have to rename your registered UserName then you have to edit the registry keys. For open the registry just press the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `regedit` and navigate to following path

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion

No at the right panel you will see the two editable entries **RegisteredOrganiztion** & **RegisteredOwner**.

[image]

In order to change either of these fields double click the field name and enter your information in the **Value data** section and click OK.

If username folder has renamed and your programs are working fine then its OK, otherwise change the `profileimagepath` to the name you have given to the **RegisteredOwner**

For this navigate to the following path in registry:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\

[image]

Comment: Did you at least try to do it yourself in XP or Vista?

Comment: @DzinX unfortunately I don't have both. I'm running the Win 7 without MS account and have Win 8 trial version. You have to give it a try at you own hand if you want to.

Comment: @DzinX I think you should have to try it on VM first. I do if I would have a MS account.

Comment: They key part of the answer is changing the `ProfileImagePath` through the registry. The other registry values are unrelated.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg did you try to change the user name through it? If that works I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @avirk: The user name has to be adjusted through other means. The values `RegisteredOwner` and `RegisteredOrganization` are unrelated. See: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/quick-tip-change-the-registered-owner-in-windows/

Answer (score 4):

From couple of hours spent researching this problem I came to a conclusion that you CAN NOT change the user folder name. Well you can but you would have to spend alot of time editing thousands of registry files. Best way to fix this is to create a new Administrator account and delete the old one. Hope this helps.

Comment: Then you'll spend hours tweaking all the settings on the new account.

Answer (score 4):

A somewhat long-winded approach (but one that might work) would be:

- use Windows Easy Transfer to 'backup' the entire user account
- delete the user (and optionally files) from the system
- create a new *local only*  (i.e. no Microsoft account) user account
- log in once as that user
- restore the easy transfer data - map the old user onto your newly created user
- change the account type of the new account to a Microsoft account (PC settings -> users -> Switch to a MS account)

Answer (score 4):

Some sub-keys under

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders

should also be updated.

Otherwise, some links in "Start" or "all apps" won't work, like Command Prompt.

(Windows Server 2012)

Comment: Had this problem with IntelliJ IDEA

Answer (score 2):

For those who do not have Windows 8 Professional, there is a way to rename the old account using command line:

Open command prompt with Right Click → Run as Admin.  In command prompt window, type

```
net user
```

and verify the old account name, ie userA.  To verify that the old account is an administrator, type:

```
net localgroup administrators
```

verify old account name is under C:\Users\userA.  To rename the old user account:

```
wmic  useraccount  where "name='userA'" rename olduserA
```

Then if successful, verify the name has changed, type

```
 net user
```

Verify that C:\Users\olduserA shows up now.  Then go to Control Panel → User Accounts → and rename the old user account display name

Then you can copy this renamed account to a newly created account if needed, skipping `NTUSER.DAT*` & `NTUSER.ini` files.

This is the method I used for a corrupt user account profile. First logged in as Administrator on win8 home, then renamed the old user account, changed the display name of old user account, created new user account with admin privs, created C:\Users\newacct and then copied most files/folders from old account C:\Users\oldacct to C:\Users\newacct. Changed the permissions on C:\Users\newacct to give full access to the newacct, removed Everyone. Then rebooted and then logged in as new account.

Voila! User profile corruption fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a more simple way to do this.

Go to regedit > Current User > Identities

Click on your username and change "Main identity" to the name you want.

Answer (score 1):

Only good for deleting folders - I was able to delete the user folder in Windows 8 by going into safemode:
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/windows-startup-settings-including-safe-mode

then going to windows explorer - Window key + E  - then double click C drive - then double click users file. Then right click on user to get rid of and delete. I had removed the account through control panel - user accounts and family safety - user accounts - remove user accounts. I had also tried to delete the user files through windows explorer first which deleted most of the subfolders. Probably best to be logged in as administrator. I would guess you can rename file that way as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is good for deleting files but I found that it screws up all your programs and settings and starts as preparing windows again. You need to be logged in as administrator from an account other than the one you want to delete or rename so you may need to set up additional accounts with administrative settings rather than standard first. It also screwed up my