# How to choose a username when using a Microsoft Account in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-account

As noted in [my other question](https://superuser.com/questions/495290/how-to-rename-user-folder-in-windows-8), Windows assigns a strange username (`<login>_000`) when logging in with a Microsoft Account to a computer for the first time. It is quite difficult to change this username (and associated folder in `C:\Users`) later.

Is it possible to choose the username during the first logging in with a Microsoft Account?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One way to do this (not very convenient, but works) is to create a local account with a desired username and then immediately connect it to a Microsoft Account.

To do this:

1. Go to Charms Bar -> Settings -> Change PC Settings -> Users -> Add a user
2. Choose *Sign in without a Microsoft Account* at the bottom of the wizard
3. Choose *Local account*
4. Enter your desired username in the *Username* field (leave password blank)
5. Press *Next* and then *Finish*
6. Switch current user to the newly created one (in the upper-right corner of the Start Screen)
7. Enter the *Users* settings exactly as in step 1.
8. Click *Switch to a Microsoft Account*
9. Enter your Microsoft Account e-mail and press *Next*
10. Complete the wizard (enter your password, fill in security info, etc.)

You'll then have a Microsoft Account with a chosen username.

Comment: This is how I did it. But I'd really like there's an option to select the user name when creating an account tied to Microsoft Account without tambourine dancing. :)

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the wrong question- you should be asking is it possible to create a user account before logging in with your Microsoft account. Yes it is possible- I don't know the exact steps, however, disabling your wifi, of unplugging your ethernet cable should leave you with no other choice than to create a local account which you would later connect to a Microsoft account, as you pointed out in your answer.

Comment: You don't have to disable anything, you just choose *Sign in without a Microsoft Account*, it's not like it's obligatory or anything (see my answer).

Comment: Right, I guess I didn't understand the question correctly then. Your answer suggests creating AN ADDITIONAL user account, rather than creating a specific-name user account from the first time you install, which your question seems to ask. I know it's not obligatory, I just didn't know if creating a new additional account had the exact same steps as creating the FIRST account on the PC, so I couldn't check. That is why I suggested going offline, just as a 'brute force' solution :)