# Windows 8.1 Pro: Why does the name of the home folder end with _000?

Tags: windows-8.1, home-folder

I just re-installed Windows 8.1 Pro and I noticed something strange about my home directory folder `C:\Users\Username`. The name of the folder instead of being Username is Usernam_000 `C:\Users\Usernam_000`. Why is that? Is this normal behavior? If not how can I change its name?

Edit 1:

As I have said in a comment all of these answers in the questions you provided as duplicates just say ways of changing the name. My principal question is why this happened. I want a way to change the name only if it is a normal situation and not a problem.

Edit 2:

As I am really curious about this "problem" I did another installation of Windows 8.1. The same thing happened again, although I deleted the partition and formatted it again.

Comment: are there multiple users on this install?  if so while not normal it is possible it is  addressing those extras as 000,001, etc etc

Comment: @linuxdev2013 no there is only one user.

Comment: and this http://superuser.com/questions/495847/how-to-choose-a-username-when-using-a-microsoft-account-in-windows-8

Comment: Thank you all but all of these answers in these questions just say ways of changing the name. My principle question is why this happened. I want a way to change the name only if it is a normal situation and not a problem .

Comment: Please provide details of any related errors in the Windows Event logs at the time u created the profile

Comment: @slayernoah there are no errors. I had just finished the installation without having touched anything else and there it was that problem.

Comment: Were you connected to the internet throughout the installation after you provided the Microsoft account details?

Comment: @slayernoah I was all the time.

Comment: If possible, try the same steps to install and use a local account instead of a MS account to see if it has the same issue (afaik, it shouldnt)

Comment: @Adam: It's normal when you use an MS Account instead of a local user account, as has been stated multiple times already below. I don't see where the problem lies or what you're so worried about.

Comment: @Karan I am worried because I didn't know that it was normal. I have installed Windows 8.1 countless times in PCs and that has never happened. Also I have tried to change the name using some suggestions from the comments and I get "access denied". A lot of people have the same problem with the renaming as I have discovered and no one knows why.

Comment: @Adam: "I have installed Windows 8.1 countless times in PCs and that has never happened." - Are you saying you installed countless times with MS (not local) accounts and this never happened?

Comment: @Karan Yes exactly that. Every time I log with a MS account. I have never installed Windows with a local account.

Comment: @Adam: That is strange indeed. I have always noted such a naming scheme for MS accounts.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if you provide a Microsoft account during installation.

If a local account is used instead, this will not happen.

You may change it as described [in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/495848/224358).

Answer (score -1):

<s>Did you do this as an OS upgrade or a fresh install? During an OS upgrade, the original folders that hold user data will be renames (such as windows.old in older versions of Windows). If you look, you will likely find your old docs in one of the folders.</s>

Edit: Windows Live account users will have their usernames truncated.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27408725/change-home-directory-name-windows-8-1

Comment: No it is a fresh install. Not only that but I deleted the old partition and then formatted it before installing Windows 8.1.

Comment: Is this system part of an AD? Did you try to migrate any files over from another location that would have been written to the User folder in question? Typically, the OS will make a different folder for the User if the username has an already existing folder in the directory. This is a common problem in AD setups when migrating profiles from one system to another. If you don't have the user logon first, when they do logon it'll create a folder "username.domain" rather than use the folder "username".

Comment: No. I noticed it as soon as the install was complete, so I didn't change anything.

Comment: Is the user account in question a microsoft account or a local user?

Comment: It is a Microsoft Account.

Comment: I think this page describes your problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27408725/change-home-directory-name-windows-8-1