# Change Win 8 Username

Tags: windows-8

I set up a new user for somebody to work on my computer, and I ended up having to reformat my harddrive (Win 8/x64).  When all my stuff was restored through carbonite, I noticed it is all on the user I created for this person. How can I either change the username or copy the contents to my main profile?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rename user folder in Windows 8?](http://superuser.com/questions/495290/how-to-rename-user-folder-in-windows-8)

Answer (score 2):

Open up the Computer Management console (compmgmt.msc) and as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Control Panel` - `User Accounts` - `Change your account name`.

@BillP3rd - The version of Windows 8 the OP is running may not have that option. I'm running vanilla Windows 8 on my laptop and the `Local Users and Groups` folder does not exist (and yes I am using an Admin account).

Answer (score -1):

If you have alocal account go to control panel and accounts  and just rename your account.

Then open a cmd and type

> net user administrator /active:yes

and reboot.After reboot login to the admin account and open cmd again

> ren C:\Users\oldname Newname

Next open "Regedit" and go to edit--> search and search for your old account's name.wherever  you find it just replace it
After youre done with regedit open cmd again and run:

> net user administrator /active:no

Reboot into your account