# How do I change my username on Windows 8? Or get around this?

Tags: windows, windows-8, firefox, batch, username

My username on my computer is
BreeBreeBRAN™

I'm trying to make a batch file to delete the firefox temp folder and run it as a task on startup.
So my batch is

cd C:\Users\BreeBreeBRAN™\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles
RMDIR 5bngz3ew.default /S /Q

But it keeps saying the path cant be found.
Even though I didnt even type it I copied it right out of windows explorer.
I read this
 [Change Win 8 Username](https://superuser.com/questions/640565/change-win-8-username)
But even after I renamed it and rebooted my pc the path is still
C:\Users\BreeBreeBRAN™\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles

If I can't rename my user then can I at least make this batch file recognize ascii?
Because whenever I put the ™ intot he batch file the output is always

C:\Users\BreeBreeBRANT\Desktop>cd C:\Users\BreeBreeBRANÖ\
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\BreeBreeBRANT\Desktop>pause
Press any key to continue . . .

It always recognizes the ™ as a T and when I actually write out the ™ it recognizes it as Ö. 
Any ideas?

I also tried going to control panel > Users > Change account name

I could just put the batch in that directory, but I still have another problem then.
I'm trying to use the batch in task scheduler to delete firefox temp files every time I log in. 
But when I tell the task the path to the batch file it says file not found.
I'm guessing the trademark symbol in my username is the cause of that too.

Answer (score 2):

The short name for the BreeBreeBRAN™ folder  maust be `BREEBR~1`. Try to use that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the environment variable for the user's temp directory like so:

```
rmdir %appdata%\Mozilla\Firefox\profiles\5bngz3ew.default /Q /S
```

Why not just change the settings in Firefox to clean up when closed?

Comment: I didnt even know there was a setting to do that.
Where is it?
Nevermind I found it.
But it only says clear history when firefx closes. That still leaves the cookies and cache behind.

Comment: Settings > Privacy > Use Custom Setting for History > Select what you want :-)

Tutorial: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/94662-firefox-browser-auto-cleanup-how-set.html

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Windows Easy Transfer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer) feature to backup all settings of your current account, create a new user with the correct name, log into this account, restore the data from the `Windows Easy Transfer` and delete the old account.