# How to change the capitalization of the user folder in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-folders

My question is very similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/890812/how-to-rename-the-user-folder-in-windows-10); I followed traintes' answer, but had limited success.

My issue is that the user folder Win10 created for me is "C:\Users\tyler" with a lower-case "t", which is quite frustrating to me, especially since it's a proper noun.

In short, the steps given in the other answer involved changing a registry key that specified the user folder path, then changing my Microsoft account's name in User Accounts. At this time, both the key in the registry and the name shown under my account are now "Tyler" with a capital "T", so those steps worked, but the actual user folder is still lower-case.

I know this may not seem like a big deal, but it is to me; I just finished clean installing Win10, so I'd like to fix this before I start installing too many things.

*Note: I haven't used superuser before, so I was unable to leave a comment about this on the linked question, sorry!*

Comment: You cannot change it, [too many registry entries pointing to the current user folder name](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/dbf6dff3-a706-4047-8dbf-58b879a9af0b/how-to-rename-a-default-user-directory-after-changing-computer-name?forum=w7itproinstall) only way is to create a new account with proper spelling and migrate old user account to new one.

Comment: But in this case it is only a change of case (unlike the case in the link) file paths and pointers should not be effected by that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

- Create a second admin user unless you already have one.
- Reboot your machine and login as the second administrator user, do not log in as `tyler`.
- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and click `Command Prompt (Admin)`

Now type:

```
rename "c:\users\tyler" "Tyler"
```

You don't have to change anything in the registry or elsewhere.

- Sign out and sign in as `tyler`

This works because `tyler` and `Tyler` are considered the same and works in all currently supported versions of Windows.

If you get an `Access Denied`, first verify the permissions on the folder:

```
icacls "c:\Users\tyler"
```

among other things, it should display:

```
BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
```

if not, you need to grant permissions first, otherwise make sure you are running as elevated admin:

```
whoami /groups | findstr /c:" S-1-5-32-544 " | findstr /c:" Enabled group"
```

This should show somethings, otherwise your account is not elevated.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you! The only caveat was that I had to put the path/folder in quotes, or else it gave me a syntax error, i.e.: `rename "C:\Users\tyler" "Tyler"`

Comment: I get "access denied" (**yes**, it's Administrator command prompt)

Comment: Yeah, don't do this. Doing this for me locked me out of my original user account after I renamed it and restarted my computer. *Luckily*, you can fix it by renaming your account back to what it originally was from the new administrator you created and restarting your computer. Basically just a waste of 15 mins.

Comment: I'm also getting an 'access is denied' error message, despite running this as admin. Any ideas?

Comment: @NatAes - I added some info about access denied.

Answer (score 2):

> **Warning:** Microsoft have now removed `lusrmgr.msc` for Windows 10 Home users. This answer no longer works for Home users.

In my installation of Windows 10 (version 1511, OS build 10586.36) the currently marked correct answer doesn't work, you still continue to get an error telling you that "Access is denied".

An alternative solution is to run `lusrmgr.msc`, double click on "Users", right click on the name you want to recapitalise and then select "Rename":

[image]

(I really wouldn't recommend changing anything more here than just the capitalisation)

After a reboot, you'll find that you have the correct capitalisation for your login, folder on the desktop and probably a couple of other places.

You won't, however, have the right capitalisation for the homegroup user, the username within the network, the folder in `c:\users` and probably a number of other places.

Comment: `lusrmgr.msc` doesn't work in Windows 10 Home Edition.

Comment: @NBlizz It did when I wrote the answer but, somewhere between then and now, Microsoft have decided to removed it - how annoying :(

Answer (score 1):

**Change User Folder name in Windows:**

1. Open command prompt with Admin Rights (Win+X -> A)
2. Type *net users Administrator /active:yes* and hit *Enter*
3. Reboot your computer. Select Administrator account to login
4. Open Registry Editor (Win+R -> Type *regedit* and hit *Enter*)
5. Go to the following key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
6. You will find several folders here like S-1-5-. Search through them till you find a ProfileImagePath pointing to your old username. Double-click on it and replace your old username with your new username
7. Go to C:\Users\ and changed the folder name to what you specified in the registry
8. Open command prompt with Admin Rights (Win+X -> A)
9. Type *net users Administrator /active:no* and hit *Enter*
10. Reboot and login to your account

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed every step of [my guide](https://superuser.com/questions/890812/how-to-rename-the-user-folder-in-windows-10?lq=1)? Because you mentioned that you have changed the path in the registry and in the user accounts settings, but you haven't changed that path in the Explorer too (or at least you did not mention it in your question!).

After you have changed the values in the registry and the user account settings, you have to reboot the machine. When you login to Windows the next time, you will be logged in with a temporary profile (because there are obviously missing references at that time!). However, you can now just open the Explorer, go to the Users directory and change the name the folder from *tyler* to *Tyler*. Then you have to restart the machine again and everything should work as expected!

PS: You have to change more references in the registry. I have updated my step by step guide a few minutes ago!

Comment: I did follow the guide, yes, and I had changed the name in Explorer too. I just meant that when I was done, the values in the registry and user account settings remained capitalized after rebooting Windows, but the folder name in Explorer did not.  Anyway, I was able to get it working as per Peter Hahndorf's answer, by changing the folder name via command line while logged in as another admin. Thanks for the update though, I'll check out your changes!