# Running C# files out of Google Drive

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio, google-drive, c#, visual-studio-2015

I like to be able to code on both my laptop and desktop (both with Win 10), therefore I have Google Drive to sync my files between the two. My first issue was that the user folder on both computers was different, but I've changed them so they'd effectively have the same path via the method in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/890812/how-to-rename-the-user-folder-in-windows-10).

However, now the issue I'm having is that my C# files keep giving me an "access is denied" error when trying to run them through Visual Studio:

> Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. error 0x80070005: Opening file from location: AppxManifest.xml failed with error: Access is denied.
>   . (0x80070005)  App1

I've tried saving them to my documents folder to which they ran with no problems, so I tried reinstalling Google Drive, but with no change. Also, just to note, I made a new project to test after each change.

Comment: Can you make sure that both folders on both PCs are exactly the same? I tried to do the same 2 years ago. I have created a project in the Google Drive directory of PC1 and it executed. Then I tried to run the project on PC2 (same name and path), but it did not run. The problem back then was that GDrive did not synchronize all files, because some file extensions were not allowed. Therefore, some files were present on PC1 (where the project was running), but not on PC2 (where the project was not running because of missing files). However, I don't know if they have changed that in the meantime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue as you but I managed to resolve this. The error you have is a logical result of the NTFS rights on your hard disk.

When installing Google Drive, the drive has been setup to only be managed by the user with the email address you provided. So, technically, the system itself has by no means access to your drive. Only you, having that email, can access it.

We can resolve your problem by adding "system" as a folder administrator of your Google Drive.

1. Go to your drive folder. Right-click and select properties:

   [image]
2. Go to the security tab:

   [image]

   3. Add the system as a user:

   [image]

   4. Set its rights to all:

   [image]

So, this should have resolved your problem.

Be sure to do this while your visual studio is closed, so no files from the drive can be altered during this process.

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive is not appropriate for storing or syncing code.You should use version control for storing and syncing code. SVN and Git are both good at this, but Git is far more common these days and you can use Git with Github for free. It allows you to sync between two computers easily, but far, more importantly, it allows you to version your code which is absolutely essential when it comes to building software.

Sign up for Github or some other Git service and store a clone of your code there. That will mean that your code is always available wherever you are, and every line will be versioned.