# Remove Microsoft linked account in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

This question refers to steps 3 and 4 in the thread [How to rename the User folder in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/890812/how-to-rename-the-user-folder-in-windows-10/955026#955026)
The troublesome steps are:

3) Remove original Microsoft linked account
4) Link local account to Microsoft account if you wish

I was stuck on those 2 steps. I couldn't find a way in Windows 10 to remove the Microsoft account.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/227763/how-to-completely-delete-your-microsoft-account/

Comment: @Moab It's about completely delete account, We just want remove local account linked to Microsoft account, Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I found it. This is so strange. After you create new local user, You should add your Microsoft account from the **email & app accounts** section and verify that. Then just remove old local account that windows created automatically. Now you have a new local account that links to your Microsoft account with the name you want.

Hope this help.