# How to Create User with specific folder c:\users\name in Windows 10 for secondary microsoft family account

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts

I like to have simple none-spacey folder names like C:\Users\Alex of my windows login account and use login with a microsoft account. I get this by creating Local user account, login, then change to microsoft account type as specified here

[How to rename the User folder in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/890812/how-to-rename-the-user-folder-in-windows-10)

Now I would like to do the same with family member, who is registered as Family Member (for Minecraft game connection) in microsoft.com. When I try to change to Microsoft account login on a second local user account it says

> another user on this device uses this microsoft account

If I in User settings > Family add user account, then I get windows determined folder name. The folder name is not that bad nowadays, its non-spaced and first five letters it seems, but I would like to specify it my self.

How do I get around this? 
(I have one convoluted solution which I found and will post but I would prefer better solution)

Comment: Easy solution: Create local user account called Alex, log into Alex, connect Alex to MS account.

Comment: Hi Ramhound, that's when it gives the error i mentioned, hence the question.

Comment: You never mentioned an error.....

Comment: It gives the error 'another user on this device uses this microsoft account', but true i didn't label it as an 'error' in the question, just as an output, but no problem, no harm done :) Probably its a new issue in build 1709 or other recent build

Comment: You never specified you were using the same MS account nor the fact you want to create a new family account....

Answer (score -1):

Bad solution below

- Remove family member from Microsoft.com
- Add new account sign in as microsoft account (directly in Family & Other people settings > Other People)
- Remove account immediately, choose to delete users data
- Login to local account
- Change login-type to microsoft account.

I would like to get rid of the first remove family member option