# How to rename the c:\users\userName folder in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I tried the solution here https://superuser.com/a/1346983/64729
and also https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/windows-10/43/win10-change-account.html

> Login to the system as an user who is in the administrator group. It
> should be a different user from the one that you are trying to change.
>
> Open File Explorer and navigate to C:\Users folder. Rename the old
> folder corresponding to the old user account

But I am not even able to rename the folder.

I shut down, restart and login as the other Administrator, and it says the folder is still open and will not allow me to rename it.

[image]

Comment: Simplest method would be to link a MS account to the local profile then unlink the MS account and when prompted for a local profile name to provide a new name.

Comment: @Ramhound how does one unlink an MS account without removing it? see https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-security-winpc/how-do-i-unlink-windows-10-from-my-microsoft/d287425e-8a22-48f7-987b-49403e754d09

Comment: You can't;  My method requires unlinking the MS account in order to create a new local profile, which will result in the creation of a new user profile (provided a new username is selected).  However, you can link the MS account, once you have created the new local profile.  My suggested method takes less then 3 minutes (plus the time to log back into the profile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely (but untested here) reason is that the folder is being guarded/accessed is its designation as a profile folder. The [tutorial from TenForums](http://tenforums.com/tutorials/89060-change-name-user-profile-folder-windows-10-a.html) edits the `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\<*User SID*>` path  *before* renaming the folder.

Answer (score 4):

A simpler way to fix Microsoft's mess is to create a hard directory link.

CMD as admin:

```
mklink /J C:\Users\myful C:\Users\MyFullName
```

The user folder myful will still be there, but you can ignore it.