# Screen setting in Windows 10 doesn't enlarge everything

Tags: windows-10, display-settings

Following [this post](https://superuser.com/a/955026/626151) I successfully changed the name of my user folder of my Windows 10 pc.

Now, since I have some vision problems, I would like to enlarge everything on my screen, as it was with the old user name.

I tried with "Make everything bigger" and "Make text bigger" (I have also restarted the system):

[image]
<sub>(the image is in Italian, I hope it's understandable)</sub>

but not everything is bigger.

For example, in the following, the objects indicated by the green arrows are enlarged, the ones indicated by the red ones are not.

Outlook and tool bar:

[image]

File explorer:

[image]

How can I make everything bigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can recognize your screenshots, you are using settings under
*Settings > Ease of Access*.

In English Windows, the setting to use is found in *Settings > System > Display*,
under "Change the size of text, apps and other items".

Comment: That works, thanks! I still can't understand why I have to enlarge to more than 150% whereas I only enlarged to 125% with the previous user (as far as I remember), and why there is a so huge difference of font size between what I marked with the green arrows and the red ones, I didn't remember such a difference previously...