# Change value of windows USERNAME env variable

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables

By default windows 10 Home has very weird system of how to choose the usernames when you create a new user in the system(in particular during intial set up).

So, when I set up my new windows 10 Home system it selected username as `Foo`. However, I want it to be `Bar`. So, according to [this description](https://superuser.com/questions/890812/how-to-rename-the-user-folder-in-windows-10#answer-1346983) I change the name of my main user account and its folder in particular. Also in resgistry I cleaned up all mentions of old `Foo` account and changed it to `Bar`(of course where it was possible). However, system variable `%USERNAME%` still gives me `Foo` when I echo it in the console(of course I rebooted after all my changes). In registry I see that system variable `USERNAME` is equal to `SYSTEM`, but I do not know from where the old user account name `Foo` appears when I try to echo its value. What does `SYSTEM` mean and how can I change the value of `USERNAME` variable?

P.S. the value of `USERPROFILE` variable shows correct value of `C:\Users\Bar`

Comment: One thing you can do is change the NAME of the computer to something sensible to you. This helps when creating nw user accounts. The registry is most definitely not a user tool. Making profile changes here can cause errors in the profile that require its deletion and creation of a new profile.

Comment: computer name can be changed very easily and I alreadt did it. One thing that I noticed there is such notion as User profile. And that user profile has an old account name in its part. Specifically profile is name as: `ComputerName/OldUserAccountName` and there is no any option to chnage it

Comment: You cannot change a user name. Only a user's display name.

Comment: Yes, and if you look in Profile settings (Advanced System Settings) you cannot change the profile name.  I set up with a Local Account first (and a good computer name) and then make my main Microsoft Account second. That has helped me.

Comment: If you are willing to do this, you can start fresh with a Local Account of your choice and then change this account to a Microsoft Account.  That works better overall.

Comment: This is a long standing bug (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/changing-user-folder-name-windows10/77a01554-1002-48f4-91c8-f438862df771) , so if this really bugs you, then you need to make a new account of your choice

Comment: @John thanks for sharing that link with me. The command `netplwiz` helped(I couldn't navigate that menu from the settings). I've read the discussion and not sure why they said that it's not possible to change the account name and account's folder name. Actually the process of changing the account's folder name is described in the link that I presented in my original post. And with help of `netplwiz` I managed to change actual username, so now `echo %USERNAME%` gives me `Bar` as I wanted. The only drawback: I had to reinstall Dropbox(in contrast Google Drive required only reconfiguration)

Comment: If I post my answer, will you acknowledge it?

Comment: @John yes, go ahead. (By the way, didn't I miss anything in the process? Myabe there are some pitfalls which I've not encountered yet?)

Comment: I did not see any errors in your posts above - Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is change the NAME of the computer to something sensible to you. This helps when creating new user accounts.

What I found in looking is that this is a long standing bug https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/changing-user-folder-name-windows10/77a01554-1002-48f4-91c8-f438862df771

So one thing you can do is make a new account of your choice.

Comment: for anybody, who is encountering this problem, also take into account this https://superuser.com/questions/890812/how-to-rename-the-user-folder-in-windows-10#answer-1346983 (+ `netplwiz` command)

Comment: Thank you for your work on this issue. Others will appreciate it.