# Windows10 - Change name on 'users' folder

Tags: windows-10, command-line

I have a simple question, how can I change name 'Develop' to some other name? You can see an example below:

> [image]

Comment: Do you ***really*** want to change the account name, or do you just want to be in a different directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rename the User folder in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/890812/how-to-rename-the-user-folder-in-windows-10)