# Can I rename user profile folder name without any problems with files?

Tags: user-folders

If I rename my user profile folder (with changing path in registry) will my files work correctly? So it won´t start giving me errors about "this file is not on this path" or something like that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this.  Follow this post:

[How to rename the User folder in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/questions/890812/how-to-rename-the-user-folder-in-windows-10)

See the second answer.

> There is no need to create a new user account, so all the settings
> associated with the existing user profile are preserved. And the only
> registry change required is to edit a single string value (the one
> that tells Windows the path of the user profile folder):
>
> ```
>     Log in by using another administrative account.
>
> Note You may need to create a new Administrative account at first.
>
>     Go to the C:\users\ folder and rename the subfolder with the original user name to the new user name.
>     Go to the registry and modify the registry value ProfileImagePath to the new path name.
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\<User SID>\
> ```
>
> That's it!

I do not do this. I just leave as is as there is not any driving need to change.

But you can do it.

Comment: This doesn't actually rename anything? It looks like the instructions are for creating a new account that has no relationship with the old one and doesn't carry over any data.

Comment: Error on my part - thank you.  I modified the answer with the correct section on renaming a folder.  My copy / paste got screwed up.  Thanks again.