# Windows 10 Home v.1809 in-place upgrade error (aiming to update to 20H2)

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I try to perform an in-place upgrade of Windows and I receive the following error

> 0x080070003 - 0x3000D  The installation failed in the FIRST_BOOT phase
> with an error during MIGRATE_DATA operation

[image]

I have tried plenty of different suggestions to no avail. Everytime the update stops and undoes the changes.

**What I did so far:**

- Stopped antivirus
- Disabled graphics card
- Deleted SoftwareDistribution folder for Windows Updates
- I did leave more than 30GB space
- Used a USB instead of mounting the image
- Cleared registry from user entries other than one user

This whole story started because the system won't update to 20H2 version (update constantly fails), and in the steps suggested I have noticed that the sfc /scannow does not finish. Stops at 72% with the error

> Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested
> operation.

but I am hopeful that if I do an in-place upgrade, I can overcome this issue.

Any help to either direction would be a lifesaver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found where to look for the correct logs.
See: [Log Files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/upgrade/log-files)

**In the end the problem was** with non-latin characters in the (only) account of the user.

I had already changed the username in the registry but Windows was smart enough to create a symlink in the user folder, rather than renaming the actual folder.

So I created a new admin account and followed [this suggested answer](https://superuser.com/a/1346983/498131) to rename the profile. And did a find and replace in the registry where needed to be sure that there are no remains of the old username anywhere.

The update finished with no problems afterwards.

Comment: all thanks to the page you've sent me :) all around the web, the only place mentioned where logs were supposed to be was inside windows folder. thank you once again

Answer (score -1):

If you need update your windows 10 device to the latest version, I would suggest you can download **Windows Update Assistant** from the following link and have a try. The Update Assistant can help you update to the latest version of Windows 10.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: Thank you for the advise but this brings me always to the same result

Comment: This does not answer the question.