# WSL reset after Windows 10 username change?

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I had to change my Windows 10 username (local account) to remove white space from the user folder("User Name" to "User-Name". I followed the advice in [this Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/890812/how-to-rename-the-user-folder-in-windows-10). I had a running install of WSL 2 in the user account i renamed.

However after the change of the username i was asked for setting user name and password on the Ubuntu Terminal again. I was able to set the same username used before in WSL and quickly found that **it seems to be a fresh install of WSL** and all of the **previous information is gone** e.g. ssh-keys.

I've read that Windows 10 manages WSL on a per user basis. So maybe the WSL for user "User Name" still exists and the configuration wasn't updated automatically. Where would i find the configuration that maps between Windows user accounts and WSL instances and is there a way to change these?

Answer (score 3):

This issue was raised in
[Bug #3720 : Renaming user profile folder breaks WSL](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3720),
where the official answer was:

> Just to make sure I'm following this correct, you did not run into
> issues until modifying the ProfileImagePath registry key? The link you
> pasted does not mention Windows 10, so I'm thinking it is not
> supported.
>
> From playing around with this a bit myself, all sorts of things fall
> over when this value is modified (including not being able to install
> store apps any longer and getting error messages when I log in). As
> such, I don't think there's much that can be done about this.

Although Microsoft does not intend fixing this problem, a workaround was proposed
by a user:

> - Installed [LxRunOffline](https://github.com/DDoSolitary/LxRunOffline)
> - Ran
>
>   ```
>     lxrunoffline rg -n 'Debian' -d C:\Users\riolly\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu20.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState
>   ```
>
>   to register my distro again; at this point, I could only log into it
>   as root;
> - Ran
>
>   ```
>     debian.exe config --default-user $my_existing_debian_user
>   ```
>
>   and was able to log in as a regular user as was the case before
>   renaming my windows user directory.

Substitute your user-name in the above commands.