# Unable to change user folder name in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

I simply wanted to change my user folder name in Windows 10.

pc\users\user-foldername

But after carrying some of the steps in this thread [here](https://superuser.com/a/1346983/729767) each attempt to do so keeps showing me an error.

> An unexpected error is keeping you from renaming this folder.
>
> Error 0x80070057

Comment: Which steps cause the error?

Comment: If your Account is a Microsoft Account, it is best not to try to change the related folder name.

Comment: @randomhero 
"Which steps cause the error?"

- Create Windows Admin account -> Folder is created in that name by Windows -> Create another Admin account -> Try to change the registry/folder name in the first account from the 2nd -> Error 

The steps are essentially as per OP.

Comment: @John
"If your Account is a Microsoft Account, it is best not to try to change the related folder name."

I wasn't sure if I understood here. The folder user name is the one created when Windows is for the first time (and subsequently for any additional users)

Comment: You are following a bad tutorial.  Changing the name of the user profile is actually pretty trivial.  You disconnect the profile from your Microsoft Account.  When this happens you are presented a prompt, to give the profile a name, and then logout of the profile and back into it.  Once you have renamed the profile you simply reconnect your Microsoft Account to your profile. The instructions you followed do NOT apply to Windows 10 (IMO). Doing the process I describe is the **BEST** way to change the name of the profile directory. I certainly have not found a batter way

Comment: If you have multiple computers with the same Microsoft Account, you would have to change all places and the account profiles in each computer have their own names.

Comment: @Ramhound If by Microsoft Account you mean the user account all Windows 10 users have to create when setting up Windows? I mean this, the folder that is created under 

pc\users\user-foldername because renaming the profile does not change this folder name (in my experience thus far).

Comment: @John Thanks, but I think that would be too involved, I may have to just live with it :(

Comment: I think just living with Microsoft Account User folder names is the best way to go. That is what I do myself.

Comment: @AlexPeterJames - It does indeed change the profile name.  I have done it multiple times on my own system.  My Microsoft Account username is to long, so it ends up shorten to something like `peggycar`, by doing what I describe, I have changed it to `Peggy Carter.`

Comment: @John Microsoft accounts will use the existing name of a local `%UserProfile%`, with two ways of naming the `%UserProfile%` what you want: (1) configure a local user first, then convert it to a Microsoft account once OOBE is exited; or (2) do what Ramhound stated if it's an existing Microsoft account. Allowing the email for a Microsoft account to be the `%UserProfile%` is inefficient due to the number of characters.

Comment: @AlexPeterJames You can't simply change the name of the `%UserProfile%`, as the name is set within numerous Registry keys and you will corrupt the user profile if `%UserProfile%` is simply renamed. The simplest way to do so is to create a new _local_ user, name it what you want, copy all data from your current user's `%UserProfile%` to the new `%UserProfile%`, log in to the new user and delete the old. This, and what Ramhound suggested, are the simplest ways to rename the `%UserProfile%` without the risk of corrupting the user profile; once corrupted, the only solution is to create a new user