# Regedit - Access denied after changing user name

Tags: windows-10, permissions, windows-registry, regedit

I'm facing the next issue; I recently changed the name of my user folder on Windows 10 (following the steps in this thread: https://superuser.com/a/949072/1665912) I didn't made a clean install on Windows, I'm using it normally (perhaps this could have been a problem).

I changed correctly, restarted the PC, entered on the temporal account, change the name of the folder in C:/ and restarted successfully my PC logging in my usual user with my new name! :)
**BUT when I try to open some installed software it crashes and I can't even download files on my windows drive**

I saw it was because the registries won't update automatically so I go and search in *regedit* my old folder name and try to replace but **when I attempt to do this an error msg prompts saying "access denied".**

Comment: There was a small part of the instructions that said " WARNING: Some programs will not follow a directory junction, and will crash as a result. "

Comment: your best bet is to create a completely new administrative user using your second favorite name, and transfer your documents etc to that using a USB drive. The programs will work again in this new login.

Comment: **You followed some really bad instructions.** Now you will have to create a new Administrator user, reverse your changes, and rename the profile the proper way.

Comment: hahah kinda happy to hear that was the instructions and not me who messed up things, @JohnnyVegas So Ok, I created the user, done. Now the USB is needed? I can't  move the files between user folders?  Is there a post/thread with these steps to follow? Sorry I don't have a lot of knowledge in this :)

Comment: @Ramhound How can I reverse my changes? Sorry for bothering is there a thread/guide with the steps to follow? :)

Comment: No need to use a USB drive @JohnnyVegas Normal copy/paste will work just as well. Only make sure you check the security permissions afterwards.

Comment: USB is far easier than having to add the broken user profile login creds to the explorer file security hellhole, plus the user does not have to logout then login to the new profile to create the file structure - they can just copy when ready.

Comment: Also, the USB drive can be handy if used with windows 10 media creation tool :) @jere_22 I think you may need to wipe and start again as you may drown in this ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a completely new administrative user using your second favorite name, and transfer your documents etc to that using a USB drive. The programs will work again in this new login.

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyVegas This work fine and I solved the permissons issue! I have only one more question: Can I move the AppData folder to my new user? (Some softwares are installed with their executables there and I want them back).
Sorry for asking too much questions, you've already help me a lot! :)

Comment: Never move, always copy - You need to copy it whilst logged in as the newer user but first add the new user to the security profile of the appdata folder, then copy.