# Name of user profile folder on Windows 10

Tags: user-profiles, windows-10

I recently installed Windows 10 on my machine. I logged in with my Microsoft account, as usual. But I noticed something strange: instead of being named "Thomas" as in Windows 8, my profile folder (in C:\Users) is named "thoma". It's not very important, but it's slightly annoying. What could have caused that? Can I change it somehow, without breaking everything?

(I'm not talking about the display name, which is "Thomas Levesque", as expected; I'm talking about the actual folder name in the file system)

Comment: Maybe [this guide for Windows 8](http://superuser.com/a/499446/50173) still is applicable for Windows 10. Have a try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rename the User folder in Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/questions/890812/how-to-rename-the-user-folder-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with Windows 10 is that it never asks for your choice of username when you log in with a Microsoft account, and offers no way to change it. The safest solution is to create a local account (which will have your desired username), and link your Microsoft account to it later (only if you want - I prefer to keep them separate).

As an aside, there is no direct way to change the display name of the local account; you would have to go to `Computer Management` -> `Local Users and Groups` and set the `Full Name`.

It seems that both problems are inherited from Windows 8 and Microsoft really wants people to move away from local accounts, for whatever reason.

Comment: Thanks. Too late to set up a local account, I guess... I'll do that next time I reinstall Windows

Comment: @ThomasLevesque  You can just login with your current admin account, and use it to create another local account (make it admin if you want)