# Windows Search Indexing After User Rename

Tags: windows, windows-10, search

Good time of the day!

Not long ago, i had to rename user which is logged in on his computer with his Microsoft Account (MA). Before he used his MA, his computer had Cyrillic username (in Russian), and as of now, we had to rename his account to username in English due to problems with some software used for development.

It wasn't hard to do, however, now we are facing problem that user is not able to use Start Menu Search function, unless direct program name provided (poweshell works, Power or Shell doesn't). We tried to run Indexation, but still, no success.

**OS:** Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
**Build:** 10.0.14393 (1607)

Any help is really appreciated!

**P.S.** We've tried all the methods mentioned in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/947392/windows-10-search-cant-find-any-applications-even-calculator?rq=1), however no signs of success. Still no apps showing while typing their name.

**P.P.S** Trying [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/how-to-repair-your-system-files-using-dism-and-sfc/1021b42a-09ff-41a0-a95a-48f3ee3ae699) now. I'll let you know if this fixes the issue. (Trying to fix problems using this thread because Indexing reported wrong permissions for user files)

**P.P.P.S** We've used [this method](https://superuser.com/questions/495290/how-to-rename-user-folder-in-windows-8) (answered on stackoverflow) to rename user folder. First part of it.

Comment: Have you reinstalled the applications?

Comment: We have no problems with displaying new applications (Github app installed after we renaimed user is displaying fine). However, any system app is missing from search results.

Comment: My suggestion would be to Reset Windows, and reinstall the applications, it's not clear what method you used to rename the user.

Comment: I've updated main question with method we've used