# Access denied renaming my user folder

Tags: windows, windows-8, permissions

I have been trying to follow [this](https://superuser.com/questions/495290/how-to-rename-user-folder-in-windows-8?newreg=58e0920cc1e642d593706f2ed0a266db) guide to rename my file system in Windows. Specifically my user folder in the Users folder. When I get to step 5 of the link I get 'Access Denied' despite opening the command prompt in administrator mode. I checked the permissions of the folder and I should have write access. I tried changing ownership of the folder to the Administrators group also and it still didn't work so I am unsure what's going on. I am using Windows 8.1 Pro for the record.

Comment: And can we assume that you have created a separate local user account with admin right to do the task?

Comment: @Darius I already had one I assume however I have been able to fix it just be swapping some of the steps from the guide.

Comment: While this is an old question, for me on Windows 10 it was because the account is not local, it's managed by my Microsoft Account (email signin).