# OneDrive not working after changing name of user folder

Tags: windows-8.1, onedrive

I manually changed the name of my user folder using the process described here: https://superuser.com/a/499446

Since then, OneDrive does not sync, and shows errors such as 0x80010007. What can I do to fix this? I already tried resetting the client and using the troubleshooting cab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case it's helpful: the solution was to turn my account into a local account and then reconnect it with my Microsoft account.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to unlink and relink your OneDrive account.

Information is here about how to move a OneDrive folder which is what you essentially did.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/wiki/odoptions-oddesktop/move-the-onedrive-folder/147dade2-830b-46ee-bf7e-36a8eab9446a

Comment: Thank you. I have done that, but no luck. The client basically crashes the minute I start it (though if I disconnect from the internet and start the client, it works until the connection is back).

Comment: Take the opportunity to make sure you are running the latest version: https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/download/

Comment: Thanks again. I'm using windows 8.1, so OneDrive is baked in.

Comment: No, that doesn't mean you are running the latest version. Especially the next generation sync client. Please download and update your client.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Get-started-with-the-new-OneDrive-sync-client-in-Windows-615391c4-2bd3-4aae-a42a-858262e42a49

Comment: The link I provided above might appear to be for business. But the point is there is a new universal client that does both and that is the version being used now. http://m.windowsitpro.com/onedrive/unification-onedrive-sync-client-here

Comment: Thanks. I tried running the executable, but said it could not proceed because OneDrive is included in 8.1

Comment: I'm not sure why that is. I've found multiple documents that the next gen client is compatible with 8.1 and even references the difference between what it comes with and what you could be running. Can you at least post what version you are running? Should be able to find it in the client settings.

Comment: Tried it again, and this time nothing happens after I run the executable. My sense is that the client crashes immediately after it tries to run.