# "Cant open access control editor. No mapping between account names and security IDs was carried out."

Tags: windows-8, permissions

I was trying to follow [this](https://superuser.com/questions/495290/how-to-rename-user-folder-in-windows-8/) guide to rename my file system in Windows which I have used in the past once before. When I tried to rename my User folder via the command prompt (in administrator mode) I received an "access denied" message. To get around this I tried to open the advanced security settings for the User folder in explorer and tried to change the ownership of it directly which produced the error message in the title. What was more worrying was that I randomnly decided to try and go to the user accounts section in the control panel and tried to click the 'Add or remove user accounts' option however nothing is happening when I click it. I am not sure whether this is related.

UPDATE: I reversed step 4 in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/495290/how-to-rename-user-folder-in-windows-8/) guide and now I can reaccess control panel and I am not getting the error. Still unsure how to proceed though.

Answer (score 0):

I made a new local account with administrator privileges and assigned that as the owner of the directory and it worked okay. For some reason when I changed the user name in Computer Management > Users and Groups for an account it meant it could not open any programs and was generally useless.