# Renamed my user folder in Windows 8 and now everything's running slow

Tags: windows-8, user

I followed [this](https://superuser.com/questions/495290/how-to-rename-user-folder-in-windows-8/) to rename my user folder which I have done before. I used the top method. This time however it hasn't seem to have worked as smoothly. Now, whenever I press the windows key and navigate to my apps there will just be grey squares for icons for my programs that are really slow to load. Also, whenever I try to open the control panel I simply can't, it will not open which is also the same for many other programs. The profile is generally slow to load as well. I have another user account that is an admin, thank god, and that loads perfectly and very fast without issue however this user account is so slow now. There's also many icons missing from my hidden icons tab in the taskbar. Something has gone wrong. Are there any ways to rectify this?

Comment: Which answer did you follow?  Update your question and specify instructions you followed.  Sounds like you should create a new user, transfer the AppData and other profile data to the new profile (copy and paste).

Comment: @Ramhound Edited. I used the top method.